# Not allowing to Create New Subscription in ssrs 2008r2

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am trying to add New Subscription IN SSRS 2008 r2 but it is not allowing message is displaying that

subscription cannot be created because the credentials use to run the reports are not stored or if a linked report the link is no longer valid.

please explain where can i give the credentials

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Data Source credentials to be stored with the Data Source; a subscription is an unattended report execution so the server needs to know how to connect to the database in these situations. Set the report Data Source up like:

[image]

And you'll be able to create Subscriptions.